# preg_match extract identifier and alias

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to extract identifier and alias from mysql ORDER BY and closest question it can help me is [Removing aliases from a SQL select statement, using C# and regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207459/removing-aliases-from-a-sql-select-statement-using-c-sharp-and-regular-expressi)

```
function test($orderby)
{
    if(preg_match('/(?<field>.*)(?:\s*|\s+AS\s+)?(?<alias>\w*)?/i', $orderby, $matches)){
        unset($matches[1]);
        unset($matches[2]);
        echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($matches,true)).'</pre>';
    }else{
        echo '$orderby doest not matches';
    }
}
```

`test("field");` works

```
Array
(
    [0] => field
    [field] => field
    [alias] => 
)
```

`test("table.field");` works

```
Array
(
    [0] => table.field
    [field] => table.field
    [alias] => 
)
```

`test("CONCAT(table.field1, ' ', table.field2) AS alias");` doesn't work

```
Array
(
    [0] => CONCAT(table.field1, ' ', table.field2) AS alias
    [field] => CONCAT(table.field1, ' ', table.field2) AS alias
    [alias] => 
)
```

`test("table.field alias");` prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => table.field alias
    [field] => table.field alias
    [alias] => 
)
```

I need in example 3 `[field] => CONCAT(table.field1, ' ', table.field2)` AND `[alias] => alias` and in example 4 `[field] => table.field` AND `[alias] => alias`

What i'm trying to do is

```
/
(?<field>.*)             #identifier
(?:\s*|\s+AS\s+)?        # without spaces (examples 1 and 2), spaces (example 4) OR 'AS' (example 3)
(?<alias>\w*)?           #alias
/i
```

What i'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use regex to do that, use an appropriate SQL parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern will work for all your examples:

```
/(?<field>.*?)((?:\s+|\s+AS\s+)(?<alias>\w+))?$/i
            │ │     │          ┊          │ │┊│
            1 2     3          4          5 267

1) Added   not-greedy operator;
2) Added   capturing group for sub-groups AS/alias;
3) Changed zero-or-more to one-or-more (at least one space is needed);
4) Removed zero-or-one for subgroup AS (at least one space is needed);
5) Changed zero-or-more to one-or-more (at least one char is needed);
6) Moved   zero-or-more from sub-group alias to group 2);
7) Added   end-of-line anchor.
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/9mnMa)**</kbd>

New capturing group is created, so you have to unset also `$matches[3]`:

```
unset( $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3] );
```

Since we add the endline anchor, I suggest you to add this line at the begin of the function:

```
$orderby = trim( $orderby );
```

Comment: Wow, great quality answer. Thank you for your effort!